# how can I prevent a console.log message from being displayed twice?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some testings and  I'm facing something really weird I created a function that refuse to take duplicated object based on the `from` property everything is Ok and I did it but something is weird happening when I console a message.

when the duplicated object occurs I got the console.log message twice I don't know why I know maybe this is silly but be easy on me I checked everything and I didn't find the issue and thank you in advance.

this is a screenshot for what I mean :

[image]

and here is my code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var data= {
  monday:[
    { from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'hello' },
{ from: '09:00', to: '13:00', txt: 'study' },
{ from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'play' }
],
tuesday: [
    { from: '7:00', to: '11:00', txt: 'watch' },
    { from: '09:00', to: '13:00', txt: 'swim' }
]
};


function hasObject({ day, object }) {
    const dataset = data[day];

    return dataset.some(entry => {

          if (entry.from === object.from) {
        console.log("the from is available");
          }
    }
  );
}

var result = hasObject({
    day: 'monday',
    object: { from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'hello' }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You console log if the `from` you give to the `hasObject` function occurs within your dataset. The `monday` object in the dataset has '55:00' two times so it's logical that it would console.log twice.

For debugging try to add the value to the console log;

```
console.log("the form is available", entry.from);
```

Comment: ... and you don't return from the function passed to `dataset.some`.  If after your `console.log` statement, you had `return true`, then `some` would stop processing after it found the first match.